# SQL Load data concurrent infile

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I am trying to run this query

```
LOAD DATA CONCURRENT INFILE 'C:\\Data-API.csv' INTO TABLE pbp_person
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
(email, first_name, last_name, title, company_name, address, city, state, zip, country, phone, vertical);
```

but I get an error saying....

`SQL Error(29) File 'C:\Data-API.csv' not found (Errcode:2)`

The file is in the right place; what's happening?

Comment: Are you sure the file is availabel ***on the server*** (where MySQL is running)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the file in the server? Because you have not specified `LOCAL`, so the file must be specified on the server host.

If it is in the client then use this:

```
LOAD DATA CONCURRENT *LOCAL* INFILE 'C:\\Data-API.csv' INTO TABLE pbp_person
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
(email, first_name, last_name, title, company_name, address, city, state, zip, country, phone, vertical);
```

Refer [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html).

> If LOCAL is not specified, the file must be located on the server host and is read directly by the server. The server uses the following rules to locate the file:
>
> - If the file name is an absolute path name, the server uses it as       given.
> - If the file name is a relative path name with one or more leading       components, the server searches for the file relative to    the
>     server's    data directory.
> - If a file name with no leading components is given, the server looks     for the file in the database directory of the default
>     database.